# Most efficient way to sleep in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

What is the most efficient way to sleep in libGDX. In Windows there is a way to tell an application to wait for a signal from the OS to continue so that the program doesn't have to spin for a certain amount of time. Does anyone know what this is called? But more specifically does an efficient way to do this exist in libGDX or Java? I am looking to make my application have as low footprint as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set non-continuous rendering so it only draws OpenGL frames when you explicitly request them. This could save a lot of battery if your game occasionally has a completely static screen. Call this, and the graphics will freeze:

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

While in this mode, `render()` is only called when you call `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();`. So you can put something like this right at the end of your `render()` method:

```
boolean shouldRender = (!animationsAreComplete || userJustTouchedScreen);

if (shouldRender) Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

You can turn continous rendering back on at any time.

Comment: This blog post has some advice about how to do this. http://bitiotic.com/blog/2012/10/01/enabling-non-continuous-rendering-in-libgdx/ A good candidate would be board games or card games that don't have a lot of motion when you aren't touching anything. Whenever stuff finishes animating, you can pause rendering until the user touches the screen again.

Comment: Add one more thing and I will mark this as the answer, suppose I do set ContinuousRendering to false, what is the most efficient way to render every 60 seconds for example. Is Thread.Sleep my most efficient option? Because I know in the Windows OS there is a way to wait for the operating system to send an alarm signal I forget what it is called rather than spin the program.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I can't think of a reason you would want to render on a schedule, because normally you would want to render when something on the screen has changed so it would always be in reaction to something. If you just render on a schedule, then when things change the user won't know until up to 60 seconds later. And when 60 seconds are up, if you haven't changed anything, then you are rendering for no reason. Anyway, I think the battery impact difference between 1fps and 1/60fps will be negligible in relation to the screen simply being on.

Comment: Android has AlarmManager for doing something similar to what you're talking about from Windows, but again I'm not sure why you wouldn't just render in response to actions the user takes and through the duration of any animations.

Comment: So to slow down animations I should just use Thread.Sleep? I am just looking for the most efficient way to do this because I will be creating as many objects as possible for an experiment I am doing.

Comment: You mean you want to set a max frame rate on the whole game?

Comment: Well yes and no, how would I set the max frame rate in the whole game most efficiently. In C# I used to use Thread.Sleep until I learned about the whole windows operating system telling the thread when to resume. Really the question is does something like that exist in Java or libGDX in general or should I just stick a Thread.Sleep to limit the frame rate and for other things.

Comment: I've used Thread.sleep in libgdx to limit the framerate in a live wallpaper before. I don't know if it's the best way, but its the only way I know. It is somewhat inaccurate. You might do the math for 25 fps and get 15 or 30. This is because Thread.sleep doesn't guarantee much precision, and mobile devices always have V-sync on. Typically, I do the math for 40fps, so it will fairly consistently get 30fps.